# Generalizing include statements in c++ files when building with make

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, g++

Hello (I am using Windows, mingw g++ compiler and mingw32-make)
To generalize my question I would like to learn how to write a c++ source file as follows:

Assuming that foo.cpp depends on foo.h where foo.cpp is in src\ and foo.h is in include\
`// foo.cpp`
`#include "foo.h"`

Normally I would just write it like this
`//foo.cpp`
`#include "..\include\foo.h"`

but I have found that as my project grows, and I begin to need more organization, that this method isn't dynamic enough. Reason being I have to change every include for every file if I want to move foo.h to a new directory (say include\bar\foo.h). Is there a way for make to achieve this. If so can it be done for header file dependencies as well.

As a side note I am new to makefiles. I am not even sure that it knows these includes are there since they are within the code (in fact from what I understand it doesn't). That would lead me to an unfortunate secondary question, which is can make see these includes? If not is it possible to change it so that it can? Feel free to answer how you would approach this problem because I have a feeling I am going about this the wrong way by putting the includes in the file rather than linking them in the makefile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is always looking into some default paths to look for .h-files. You can add your path.

For example `gcc` takes multiple `-I` arguments which contain a path. In your `foo.cpp` you do:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

and when compiling you say:

```
g++ -I../include foo.cpp -c [other options]
```

.

Regarding the second part of your question: The `makefile` and the call to `make` does not normally know anything about the files to be compiled and about your project. However there are several default variables and directives in make which lead to that impression: It could be, that in your environment you only need to change the `CFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS` variable to add the `-I`-argument and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the very fast reply and straightforward answer. I will try it when I have access to the project again.

Answer (score 2):

Patrick B has answered very well on how to make the compiler know where to include from, but not the following bit:

> As a side note I am new to makefiles. I am not even sure that it knows
>   these includes are there since they are within the code (in fact from
>   what I understand it doesn't). That would lead me to an unfortunate
>   secondary question, which is can make see these includes? If not is it
>   possible to change it so that it can?

No, make doesn't understand what your source files contain, or how they depend on other files [make also doesn't really care if you are programming in C, C++, Fortran, Pascal, ADA, Lisp, Cobol or Haskell - as long as there is a "If you have a file like this, and want a file like that by doing something" relationship between files, make will sort it for you.

There are several ways to do this. You can manually add:

```
 foo.cpp: foo.h
```

Or you can use a dependency file for your include-file, and let `make` built it automatically, by adding this, for example:

```
 SOURCES = foo.cpp    # Add any further source files here. 
 INCLUDES = -I../includes   # Add other include directories if needed. 

 CFLAGS += ${INCLUDES}

 TARGET = foo.exe   # in Windows. Just foo in linux/MacOS.

 all: ${TARGET} deps.mk

 ${TARGET}: ${SOURCES}
     gcc -O $@ $^      

 desp.mk: ${SOURCES}
     gcc -MM ${INCLUDES} $^ > $@

 include deps.mk
```

Note that makefiles are RELYING on indentation being tabs. This post uses spaces, so you will need to "tabify" the recepies. Also note that in a "proper" makefile, you'd make `foo.o` from `foo.cpp`, etc, and link all the different `.o` files together. That way, the compile is a fair bit quicker for large projects. I've simplified it for readability.

Maybe I should expand a little bit:

`gcc -MM` gives a list (to standard out) of the files that are being "compiled" and all of it's dependencies. It doesn't actually compile the code (and as long as the code is at least SOMEWHAT) close to being compileable, it will happily process your files.

For more details on `gcc -MM` and related, have a look at the [GCC invocation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html) documentation.

The `$@` and `$&^` are what `make` calls "Automatic variables" - they expand to the "target" (easy to remember, as it looks sort of like a target for shooting arrows at or similar) and "all dependencies" (no visual clue here, I'm afraid - and every now and again, I have to remind myself) respectively. Check out [here](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for more details.

Comment: To supplement:  Some compilers have an option, e.g. -M, to generate a dependency file for `make`.

Comment: Yes, that's what `gcc -MM` is - `-M` also lists standard library files, which is usually not needed in the makefile [as they usually don't change very often, and even more rarely in ways that actually affect the program].

Comment: You and Patrick have hopefully answered my question perfectly. I will get back to you with the results when I find the time to test this.